# FlashLite 2.x/3.0 Cross Domain policy file

Tags: flash, sockets, actionscript, policy, flashlite

As per my understanding of the Adobe docs for a cross domain request by an swf, two types of policy files are required on the server:

1. URL policy file:  this is named "crossdomain.xml" and stored in the root of the server and is generally an http request to the server.
   `System.security.loadPolicyFile("http://foo.com/crossdomain.xml");`
2. Socket policy file: this is requested via xmlsocket protocol and on port 843 using say `System.security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://foo.com:843");`

The question is if my FLashLite client is only going to be talking to the server using Sockets(via xmlSocket) do I still need to ask for crossdomain.xml over http, or can I skip step 1 and directly ask for the socket policy file at step 2?

Answer (score 1):

If your FlashLite client resides in the same domain, you don't need an http `crossdomain.xml` file even if you are going to communicate with the server through http - `crossdomain.xml` is needed for cross-domain accesses, not for same domain accesses.

xmlsocket policy files are required no matter where your swf resides - that's different.

Comment: my flashlite client doesn't reside on the same domain. Is that case what is necessary